# yup.number().typeError() not cheking for character other than dot(.)

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I use yup for validation along with formik . I was using `typeError()` for checking wether the number contains any other characters than numbers. It works properly with character dot(.), but not working for other characters.

This is my validation code:

```
credits: Yup.number()
      .required('general.mandatory')
      .typeError('settings.credit_not_allow_decimal_validation_text')
      .min(1, 'settings.credit_credit_range_validation_text')
      .max(100000, 'settings.credit_credit_range_validation_text')
      .positive('settings.credit_not_allow_decimal_validation_text')
      .integer('settings.credit_not_allow_decimal_validation_text')
```

I'm also posting the versions of formik and yup

> "formik": "^0.11.11", "yup": "^0.25.1"

I'll also post images of errors I'm supposed to get

[image]
// Validation error shown

[image]
//No validation error shown

I want to have like detecting any characters other than numbers used to throw error message while using Yup.number(). Please help Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox?

Comment: @Fraction Sorry ,but, I'm not able to provide one with the yup version I'm using. :(

Comment: you can fork this one https://codesandbox.io/s/little-framework-lwof2

Comment: @Fraction I'm getting a screen saying

 Could not find module in path: '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault' relative to '/node_modules/yup/lib/index.js'

Answer (score 1):

At last after some updates i found out that this issue was fixed with updating my formik and yup libraries to their latest versions

The current versions are:

> "formik": "^2.1.4", "yup": "^0.28.1"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. It was because the input type was number. When an input type is number, it's value will never become a non-number, even though it will display non-numeric characters. Try typing in these two boxes to see what I mean:

```js
document.getElementById('testinput1').addEventListener('input',
  function changedVal(event) {
    document.getElementById('test1').textContent =
      JSON.stringify(event.target.value)
  }
)

document.getElementById('testinput2').addEventListener('input',
  function changedVal(event) {
    document.getElementById('test2').textContent =
      JSON.stringify(event.target.value)
  }
)
```

```html
numbers only:
<input id="testinput1" type="number"/>
<span id="test1"></span>
<br/>
anything:
<input id="testinput2" type="text"/>
<span id="test2"></span>
```

In the numeric field "2$33" becomes an empty string "", so it's validated as being empty by Yup.